# Check whether some address belongs to the given memory block

Tags: c, pointers, memory

Is there any way to do this? Properly speaking, I need a portable way, but non-portable one would be useful too. Thanks.

**Clarification:** I got a `buffer` that contains zero terminated string (or many strings, as it may be when using strtok) and I need to copy string pointed by an *arbitrary* pointer (`new_string`) to that buffer. As far as I don't know actual buffer size (let us say, it's impossible), I need to realloc it (except in the case of `strlen(buffer) >= strlen(new_string)` - here `buffer` definitely has enough room to store `new_string`) and then copy `new_string` to reallocated buffer. And here's the problem: if `new_string` points to string somewhere inside `buffer`, it may become invalid after realloc. So I need to detect this special case and handle it appropriately.

Comment: Yea - but it depends on what information  you stored when you allocated the block. Some compilers will store size of allocated block just below the pointer but you cannot rely on that behavior - so if you need this you have to do some bookkeeping of your own

Comment: It would really help to clarify your question - give an example of what you are trying to do in code.

Answer (score 1):

Non-portable but likely to work:

```
if (p >= block_start && p < block_start + block_len)
```

If the types don't match, you should cast them all to `char *`.

The reason the above solution is non-portable is that pointer comparisons are not defined except between pointers to elements of the same array. With most real-world compilers they "work" and do what you expect, but there's no requirement that they do, and on segmented architectures or implementations with advanced bounded pointers, etc. they might not.

The portable (but very slow) way is:

```
for (i=0; i<block_len; i++)
    if (p == blocK_start + i) // pointer points inside the block
```

Note that for this version to work all the pointers should point to a character type.

Comment: The second reason is that there's no portable way to detect block size, afaik.

Comment: Note that if `block_len` is in `char` units (i.e. it's the exact value passed to `malloc`), you need to cast to `char *` anyway to make the end calculation correct. Likewise, if `block_len` is in some larger unit (i.e. `malloc` got `block_len * sizeof(something)`), you need to correct that when you cast to `char *` for another reason.

Comment: @nitrocaster Well, keep track of how much you allocated. Takes some discipline, but is fully portable.

Comment: @delnan: Thanks. Yes, it's best to work in `char *` everywhere here.

Comment: @delhan, no way. I can't modify allocation logic because it's necessary to keep compatibility with pointers returned by standard malloc.

Comment: @nitrocaster So you are handed pointers to arbitrary allocated blocks, with no size information? You should edit more information, including what you're actually trying to do, in the question then.

Comment: @nitrocaster: There is no solution if you don't keep track of the size information. Are you trying to implement some kind of garbage collection? If so, just don't. It's not possible in C and you'll make a huge mess of unreliability and randomness.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you `realloc` if `strlen(new_string) > strlen(buffer)` (although presumably you mean the size of the buffer as it might not exactly contain a string). However, if `new_string` points into `buffer`, and `new_string` is actually a string, then `strlen(new_string)` cannot possibly be bigger than the buffer size.

So if you find `strlen(new_string) > buffer_size` then you know it is safe to realloc because `new_string` can't be in the buffer.

Also, note that it's undefined behaviour to `strcpy` between two buffers that overlap. (The `strcpy` function doesn't have to do `while (*s++ = *t++);` - it could start from the other end , or use some optimized technique that copies chunks, etc.).  If you need to support this function copying from one part of the buffer to another, it'd be safer to use `memmove` plus manually moving the null terminator.

Comment: > _You say that you realloc if strlen(new_string) > strlen(buffer)_  

Actually, I always do realloc. It's just a special case when it's not required, but this case can be ignored.

> _although presumably you mean the size of the buffer as it might not exactly contain a string_  

No, I mean exactly strlen(buffer), because it's impossible to detect buffer size.

Comment: > _So if you find strlen(new_string) > buffer_size then you know it is safe to realloc because new_string can't be in the buffer._  


You're wrong. Let me show an example:  

`char *buffer = strdup("foo foobar"), buffer[3] = '\0'; // buffer : "foo"`
`char *new_string = buffer+4; // new_string : "foobar"`
`my_strcpy(&buffer, new_string); // problem here`

Comment: That isn't a problem; the buffer size is 11 and the new string length is 7 (including terminator).  If you're trying to determine the existing buffer size using `strlen`, and then doing `realloc`, that's a pretty feeble design.  Consider either tracking the actual allocation size, or using `malloc` instead of `realloc`.

Comment: > tracking the actual allocation size --- This is library code that should work with standard allocators. ... or using malloc instead of realloc --- performance hit, because realloc is potentially faster then malloc+free.